# Detecting all mouse and key events in app

Tags: macos, cocoa

in my app I would like to keep a time stamp which updates every time a mouse or key event is triggered.
How can I detect these events within my app?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [`NSEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html) methods `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` and `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` (depending on whether you want to track events in your own apps or other apps).

Comment: Worked out perfectly!